# I'm trying to upload a picture in CodeIgniter but it's not working

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-uploading, codeigniter-3

Good day! I made a form to upload a picture of a product to my database and to show the product on another view page but its not really working.

This is my form in my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Product/product_form'); ?>" method="post">


      <h2> Cadeau aanbieden</h2>

        <table class="aanbieding-cadeau">
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'placeholder' => '1. Naam van het cadeau', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo($selectField);?></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'placeholder' => '3.Kies een stad', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Gebruik adres van mijn account</label>
</div>

          <td>
            <h4>Upload foto</h4>

              <?php
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
    $arr = array('name' => 'product_foto', 'type'=>'file');
echo form_open_multipart();
    echo form_upload($arr);
       echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');

    ?>
           </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'placeholder' => '5. Vertel iets over dit cadeau..', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadeau aanbieden!</button>
         </td>
        </tr>     
      </table>
    </form>
```

And this is the code in my view thats not working to upload a picture:

```
  <?php
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
    $arr = array('name' => 'product_foto', 'type'=>'file');
echo form_open_multipart();
    echo form_upload($arr);
       echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');

    ?>
```

When i send the form no picture is loaded and no picture is added to my image folder.

This is my product controller:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Product extends CI_Controller { 


    var $data = array();

     public function index()
 {

  $this->load->view('product_form', $this->data);


    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products');
    $image_id = $query->num_rows() + 1;

  $config = array (
   'upload_path' => './upload/',
   'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
   'max_size' => 0,
   'filename' =>    $image_id

   );

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);          

   if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
   $this->db->insert('products', array(
       'product_foto' => $this->upload->file_name
));
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Success');
   }


 }


 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('product_model');
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }

 public function product_form()
 {
  $save = array(
      'product_naam'          => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
      'product_beschrijving'          => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
      'product_categorie'   => $this->input->post('product_categorie'),
      'ophaal_plaats'   => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'), 
      'product_foto'  => $this->input->post('product_foto'),
      'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
      'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
        );

   $this->product_model->saveProduct($save);
  redirect('https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/AlleCadeausController');
 }
}
```

NOTE: When I use this code outside my normal form I can upload a picture to my database and the picture does get added to my folder:

```
<?php
echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
echo form_open_multipart();
echo form_upload('file');
echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
echo form_close();
?>
```

Hope someone can help me out,
Thanks

Comment: please set your normal form **enctype="multipart/form-data"** if its work..not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, there has some furnishing issue.

1. Add enctype attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form which is essential to upload image.
2. There is no need to use double submit button. So remove **echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');** from your view.
3. You used form tag above of your view. So no need to use **echo form_open_multipart();** again in your view.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, enctype is required when you do any file upload.

So your form will be looks like give below.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Product/product_form'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

**Note:** The enctype attribute can be used only if `method="post"`.

> Syntax : `<form enctype="value">`

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded** : Default. All characters are encoded before sent (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values)

**multipart/form-data**:    No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

**text/plain**: Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded